# I am trying to update the command line output 3 times using \r in C, but why does it skip over my second printf statement?

Tags: c, sleep, fflush

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello");
    sleep(1);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\rworld");
    sleep(1);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\r!    \n");
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

It displays "Hello" for a second, does nothing for another second, and then goes straight to "!" I have tried to change the sleep durations and a few other things but nothing has fixed it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try flushing directly after your printf s rather than before them? It isn't skipping your printf s Its just not necessrily on the screen for very long before you overwrite it.

Comment: Yes, if you wait until just before the next output you may not even see it, if it overwrites it.

Comment: @AviBerger Thanks! Switching the fflush and sleep fixed the issue!

Comment: You could try `fprintf( stderr, "Hello" );` as (I believe) `stderr` is not buffered. No need for the calls to `flush()`... Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Flush before sleep to insure timely display.

`stdout` buffering mechanisms are implementation defined.  Yet `fflush()` will get the output done promptly.

```
int main(void) {
    printf("hello");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);

    printf("\rworld");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);

    printf("\r!    \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```